# how to access the child class through abstruct class in Java?

Tags: java, xml, abstract-class

I have the following code in Java:

```
class Info {
    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlElementRefs({@XmlElementRef(name="apple", type="Apple.class")})
    final private List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();  

    public Info() {
    }

    public List<Fruit> getFruits() {
        return fruits;
    }
}

public abstract class Fruit {
    @XmlElement(name = "label", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
    String name = null;

    public Fruit() {
    }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="apple")
public class Apple extends Fruit {
    @XmlElement(name = "age", required = true)  
    int age;

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}

<config>
  <Info>
    <apple>
      <age>20</age>
    </apple>
  </Info>
</config>
```

Then in the main class, how could I access class `Apple` to get the age of the apple?

```
class Main() {
    private List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

    public void getAge() {
        Info info = new Info();
        fruits = info.getFruits();
    }
}
```

so in the main class, we get a list of fruit, but how to access the `getAge()` method of Apple class?

Comment: Cast it to Apple, then call `getAge`?

Comment: And before that (appying the cast), testing whether the instance you're dealing with is indeed an Apple ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, note that you cannot be sure that your `Fruit` object is an instance of `Apple`, and that your `fruits` object is not a single `Fruit` but a `List<Fruit>`.

That said, assuming you want `getAge` to return the age of the first `Apple` in the list, you can do something like this:

```
public void getAge() {
    int age = -1;
    for(Fruit f : fruits) {
        if(f instanceof Apple) {
            age = ((Apple)f).getAge();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add abstract method to the class Fruit:

```
public abstract class Fruit {
    @XmlElement(name = "label", required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NormalizedStringAdapter.class)
    String name = null;

    public abstract int getAge();

    public Fruit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: In the case you need age on all the fruit sub classes.

Comment: Exactly! But there is no common way to "access" the method from child class without this method in parent class.